# truncate table taking very long time, is it normal?

Tags: mysql

I am using    truncate table table_name;    on a table with around 1 million rows, but it's been taking too long, running since last 3 hours.

Is it normal? Can you suggest some other way to delete all rows from a table, which could be faster?

Comment: Also, please check: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68184

Comment: What are the stats on your machine?

Comment: i have killed the query, by the time i killed it already deleted 600 thousand records, but since data was not important to me so i just copied the structure of old table to a new one and then dropped the old one.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Truncate wont work in some cases such as ,

when you have index kind of things and some foreign key constraints

Easy way i suggest is

```
RENAME TABLE table_name TO t1;

CREATE TABLE table_name LIKE t1;

DROP TABLE t1;
```

or you can also use `DELETE FROM table_name;`

Comment: This saved us a ton of time - truncate wasn't working because of foreign key references, but we needed to get rid of a logging table that was ~22GB in size (over 23M rows) and this made it so much faster.

Comment: This works for me like a charm! Thanks!

To add something, I was also checking it through a UI client (DBeaver) and it happens sometimes that when you list the data through the table directly it does not get disconnected even if you close the tab

Answer (score 4):

I believe deadlock occurs during your query execution, so it's better to kill it .

I used to delete lots of data, by  deleting small chunk in a single query (10k works fine).

So you might write some script which will do this for you.

Comment: if truncate is slow i am thinking of creating a new table with same structure and then dropping the old one, i think that will be quite fast. pls share ur views on this.

Comment: the problem I had was that a stale connection was stuck doing a commit to the table so it was frozen.

Answer (score 1):

Given issue is logged in mysql repo. For more details visit https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68184

In my case, I was trying to trucate table using JDBC But due the above i was not able to do that.
So was going through below alternative.

```
    String createTmpTable = "create table tmp_" + tableName + " like " + tableName;
    String dropTable = "drop table " + tableName;
    String reCreateTable = "create table " + tableName + " like tmp_" + tableName;
    String droptmpTable = "drop table tmp_" + tableName;
```